# Can I reinstall Wamp on Windows 10 without overwriting my databases?

Tags: mysql, installation, wamp

I have another open question which at the moment seems to be a bit tricky to answer:

[phpMyAdmin - Cannot login even when changed password](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186892/phpmyadmin-cannot-login-even-when-changed-password)

I am hoping someone can still answer it. I think one of the config files or ini files is wrong in some way.

So I need to ask this question as a back up.

**I have a few databases in my present install of Wamp server on Windows 10. Can I reinstall, or do a repair-install, on this Wamp server without overwriting or deleting my databases?**